# F5 Networks VPN

Tags: vpn, f5-big-ip

I have a Windows 2008 server which needs to establish a VPN connection to a company that is using a product from F5 Networks.

They sent a VPN URL, username and password to me for establishing the connection.  However, I need this to work from a server and can't have a constantly logged in user on the box.

I believe the product they are using is called BIG-IP.

When I do a "ipconfig /all" after connecting I see the following:

```
PPP adapter [removed company name]-netaccess - Go to [removed company website].com instead of dialing directly:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : [removed company name]-netaccess - Go to [removed company website].com instead of dialing directly
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.254.254.2(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

It looks like the client I currently have access to is solely for use with a browser; and their support department is crap.  You can't call them and we've been waiting 4 days just to get a simple response back.

I'm not familar with F5.  Do they have a standard client I can just install to get this going?  I looked on their site but couldn't locate anything I thought was relevant... but I'll be the first to admit I'm in unchartered territory here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CLI Client, this works with Firepass, EDGE & BIGIP APM.
http://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/FirePass.ClientCLI.ashx

-md

Answer (score 1):

You are potentially looking for the F5 Edge Client.  I can't seem to find a direct download from F5, but there may be a download link available if you contact the VPN provider's support.

Comment: I found a BIG-IP Edge client, installed it and connected.  Is there any way to configure this to be an "on demand" type of thing.  From the looks of it I still need to have a user logged into windows for it to operate.

Comment: There is no feature builtin for 'run as service', but there are third party utily to assist to achieve what you wish. But there may be one catch and kind of defeats the purpose, you may need to save credentials on the client... Not sure how sophisticated the BIG-Edge device is but if it allows single user to save credentials then you may just be in luck.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is mostly correct, however the F5 also supports termination of [IPSEC connections](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/14000/100/sol14169.html). However, the ESP traffic is extremely difficult to configure and this really is a PITA to configure and is considered a dark art even among F5 employees. If you can barely get F5 to get this working for you, then I suspect you have little hope of getting it working using the crummy support it sounds like you get from the partner you are working with. Good luck anyway!